# Rails, use a form field to set something on the user registration (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I would really like to add a form field "invite_code" to the user sign up form, but I don't know how to add the invite_code to the controller so that the application knows how to look for it?

The form in the sign up on the template would read:

```
<% form_for User.new do |f| %>
   <span>Email:</span> <% f.email %><br>
   <span>Name:</span> <% f.name %><br>
   <span>Invite Code:</span> <% f.invite_code %><br>
<% end %>
```

The "invite_code" isn't part of the database or anything, but in the user registration model, I want to put a:

```
before_save :invite_promo
def invite_promo
    if @invite_code.present? && @invite_code == "special_person"
        self.special_key = true
    end
end
```

Is there an easy way to look for form fields in the template using the model or controller?
So sorry...I'm new to Rails.  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a virtual attribute `invite_code` in `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :invite_code
```

Your form should look as follows:

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
   <span>Email:</span> <%= f.email_field :email %><br>
   <span>Name:</span> <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
   <span>Invite Code:</span> <%= f.text_field :invite_code %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You may also need to  permit extra params

Comment: I added that in the User model, but I'm still getting a 'undefined method'
View:
<div class="input">
       <label for="">Invite Code?</label>
       <%= f.invite_code :invite_code, :class => 'submit' %>
</div>

and then I added the attr_accessor above...what I am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to create a field inside your table, you can use hidden field in view like, `<%= hidden_field_tag :invite_code, 'code' %>`